# I would like to remove an existing 3 piece bath surround and replace crumbling plaster wall with green board

Tags: bathroom, repair, walls

The bathroom is in a rental house I own.  There is a three piece surround installed by a previous tenant about 10 years ago that is in good shape.  Tenants who occupied for 8 years have moved out and I find the the wall at the bottom of the surround has given way--I have removed the caulking and find one can push the surround in on all sides. The problem does not appear to exist at the top.  The tub's fixtures are in an interior wall as is the long axis of the tub.  I have an access door to the plumbing connections  in an adjacent closet. From that access I can see the bottom of the wall at the fixtures has disintegrated with the surround adhesive coming off in thin sheets...almost like paper.  (Is this faulty/incorrect adhesive?) I wondered if it is possible to remove the surround, tear out the existing plaster?(plaster)/wallboard(?) green board the wall and then reinstall the surround.  From what I see the surround was not well affixed to the wall.  What problems do you expect me to have with such a plan?  Thanks!  Phil in Rochester NY

Answer (score 1):

Glad you realize you have to rip out everything. There's probably more damage than you realize that you'll find as you remove the surround so be prepared for that. My one recommendation would be is to use cement board instead of green board. Since you're removing the complete surround, think about removing all the existing wall and cement boarding the entire enclosure, it wouldn't take that much more work and you'll prevent future problems. The surround was probably put in to hide/fix wall damage so that's why it's coming off easily. If it's difficult to remove in some sections, use a putty knife to separate it from the wall. If the surround is in good shape, you should be able to reuse it. Do a thorough job of caulking the seams of it and where the faucets protrude from it, the faucet and shower head flanges.

Comment: Been there, done that...I mirror Jack's answer. I would give it 10 upvotes if I could.